# Switching branch does not update android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, git-branch

I have a stable branch that I am doing some work on. Then to do some experimental stuff, I create another branch called experi and then started doing some work there. Then I switch back to my stable branch. However, android studio is still showing the code for the experi branch. How do I make it so that when I switch from one branch to another, android studio switches content?

I created the branch using

```
git checkout -b experi stable
```

and then to switch I do

```
git checkout experi
```

basically how do I keep the branches independent?

At least I want to be able to go back to my stable branch (before the news stuff intended for experi)

Comment: When you create a branch, why do you want another branch name beside your command git checkout -b experi stable (In this case, why do you need stable). git checkout -b experi and git checkout experi, should take you to experi branch. Once done, do a commit in experi branch and then do git checkout stable, should bring you back to stable branch

Comment: `git checkout -b experi stable` means I am creating experi from stable. That is just the original step: experi has to come from somewhere. Then later in time ... hours later... I want to be able to switch back to branch stable without it being aware of anything that happened on branch experi. So `git checkout stable` should do that. But it turns out it's not doing that. The branch switches, but the experi code is till there in the IDE.

Comment: you have to commit your changes to the experti branch. then switch back to stable ( http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/branches-1 )

Comment: you mean like this: `git add .` and `git commit -a -m "comments here"`? done that.

Comment: Have you tried doing a `gradle sync` after switch?

Answer (score 2):

This is so weird. Everything I did was correct. But in order for the IDE to refresh I have to click on the bottom tab labeled "Version Control". It is next to the "Android Monitor" tab.

Comment: You could also use Synchronize button from menu to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio doesn't sync with your git repo. Make sure you are on the desired branch. Note: SourceTree , AS can indicate you are on a different branch . But the command line  never lies.

**Synchronize your gradle** and clean the project.

In Android Studio : View > Tools Windows > Gradle

[image]